# How to use t-if to make condition in row number

Tags: odoo, qweb

i try to modify a row in report invoice in odoo 11, i need condition about number of row generated by report after click in"Print" button to make

```
<t-if="number_line_in_table== 1">
   <!--DO something..-->
</t>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do a Python-style `enumerate`, but you can just use an old-fashioned counter, such as below.

```
<t t-set="counter" t-value="0"/>
<t t-foreach="records" t-as="record">
    <t t-set="counter" t-value="counter + 1"/>
    <t t-if="counter == 1">
        <!-- Do Something. -->
    </t>
</t>
```

Here is [an example](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/addons/website_event/views/website_event.xml#L454) where they do this in core.

Here is the [QWeb Documentation for Odoo 12](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/qweb.html) with more information.

---

As for your specific example, you want to inherit an existing view to include a `counter` inside of that view's existing `t-foreach` element.

**Relevant part of the Existing View**

```
<tr t-foreach="o.order_line" t-as="line">
    <td>
        <span t-field="line.name"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span t-esc="', '.join(map(lambda x: x.name, line.taxes_id))"/>
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
        <span t-field="line.date_planned"/>
    </td>
    <td class="text-right">
        <span t-field="line.product_qty"/>
        <span t-field="line.product_uom.name" groups="product.group_uom"/>
    </td>
    <td class="text-right">
        <span t-field="line.price_unit"/>
    </td>
    <td class="text-right">
        <span t-field="line.price_subtotal"
            t-options='{"widget": "monetary", "display_currency": o.currency_id}'/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**How you can use a counter**

*Disclaimer: I have not done something in quite this way before. It may or may not work exactly like this. If you are unable to get it working through inheritance, then you can `replace` the entire `foreach` loop via `xpath`, if necessary.*

```
<xpath expr="//tr[@t-foreach='o.order_line']" position="before">
    <t-set="counter" t-value="0"/>
</xpath>
<xpath expr="//tr[@t-foreach='o.order_line']/td[1]" position="before">
    <t-set="counter" t-value="counter + 1"/>
    <t t-if="counter == 1">
        <!-- Do Something. -->
    </t>
</xpath>
```

Comment: thanks, but i use external xml file : foreach is in odoo xml file, and my module contain xml file that inherit the xml file of odoo report, so in my xml file i didn't have foreach tag to use your example, and i should not modify xml files in odoo/addons

Comment: Which XML file are you inheriting from core?

Comment: inherit_id="purchase.report_purchaseorder_document"

Comment: And which Odoo version are you using?

Comment: odoo 11, i need make  a condition (t-if) but i which is the rows value  number  and current iteration number  ? i find in https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/qweb.html that we can use $as_index and $as_size, but how use that in example of t-if ?